# NLTK Generate sentences without two occurences of the same word in Python

Tags: python, nltk, context-free-grammar, linguistics

I am using this NLTK code to generate sentences from demo_grammar (see below), and the problem is that with grammar rules like N N or N N N I end up with sentences like "creation creation creation". I am only interested in generating sentences where the same word doesn't occur twice (i.e. creation video software).

How could I do that?

The `generate.py` from NLTK is as such: https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/parse/generate.py

I have tried the demo code from the `generate.py`:

```
from nltk.grammar import CFG
from nltk.parse import generate    

demo_grammar = """
  S -> NP VP
  NP -> Det N
  PP -> P NP
  VP -> 'slept' | 'saw' NP | 'walked' PP
  Det -> 'the' | 'a'
  N -> 'man' | 'park' | 'dog'
  P -> 'in' | 'with'
"""

def demo(N=23):

    print('Generating the first %d sentences for demo grammar:' % (N,))
    print(demo_grammar)
    grammar = CFG.fromstring(demo_grammar)
    for n, sent in enumerate(generate(grammar, n=N), 1):
        print('%3d. %s' % (n, ' '.join(sent)))
```

Comment: Every rule expansion is independent of the others; that's what a **context-free** grammar is. Is rewriting the grammar an option? You could do what you want by leaving the terminals out of your grammar, and putting them in as a separate step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite the grammar as suggested by alexis, this means several list of terms (nouns, verbs,...) for a specific place in each sentence.

But you can also apply a post-filtering strategy (don't have to touch grammar) :

- generate all possible sentences with your grammar, even sentences with words occuring twice or more
- apply a filter that removes all sentences with words occuring twice or more

Here is the filter you can apply :

```
from collections import Counter
f=lambda sent:False if Counter(sent.split(" ")).most_common(1)[0][1] > 1 else True

f("creation video software") # return True, good sentence
f("creation creation creation") # return False, bad sentence
f("creation software creation") # return False, bad sentence
```

Comment: Nice and simple, but the reason I suggested modifying the grammar is that this filter necessarily removes too much: You'll throw out "the cat sat on the mat", for example. ("the" occurs twice, horrors!) And there's no way to restrict it since the output doesn't have structure or even parts of speech. But hey, if it's good enough for the OP...